# Quelle est l'abréviation correcte de « monsieur » ?

Tags: standard, abréviations

J'ai souvent entendu dire que *Mr.* est un anglicisme : l'abréviation de *mister*, et que *M.* est l'abréviation correcte en français — *correcte*, comprenez *la plus ancienne*, *originale*. À l'occasion, certains ajoutent que *M<sup>r</sup>* est correct.

Cependant, d'autres sources, entre autres [langue-fr.net](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article179), prétendent que ce *Mr.* est tout à fait correct.

Qui croire alors ? Quelles abréviations sont correctes ? Et plus important : comment ces abréviations sont-elles perçues par les francophones ?

Comment: Complément d'information pas exactement relié: si l'abréviation comprend la dernière lettre du mot, on ne met pas de point. Sinon, oui. Exemple: _M._ pour Monsieur, mais _Mme_ pour Madame.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

« M. » est l'abréviation usuelle de « monsieur » en français.

[« M<sup>r</sup> »](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/abr%C3%A9viation/199) est une abréviation bien formée de « monsieur » en français qui a été en concurrence avec « M. » (voir l'entrée du *Littré* en lien qui donne « Mr » comme exemple d'abréviation ; Grevisse ne condamne « Mr. » qu'à cause du point qui serait un usage anglais, il ne cite simplement pas « M<sup>r</sup> ») mais est souvent perçue de nos jour comme un anglicisme.

La français forme ses abréviations par un des mécanismes suivant :

- la première lettre du mot suivie d'un point ;
- les premières lettres du mot, généralement la dernière lettre utilisée est une consonne et la première lettre omise une voyelle, suivie d'un point ;
- les premières lettres du mot suivies en exposant des dernières et sans point. La mise en exposant est souvent omise en écriture manuscrite (et parfois ailleurs), en particulier quand l'abréviation ainsi formée n'est pas prononçable (« Mlle » mais on évite « Cie » pour « compagnie »).

Un mécanisme auxiliaire employé généralement pour des mots d'origine latine et parfois pour éviter des ambiguïtés est d'utiliser les premières lettres du mot suivies d'une consonne intérieure et d'un point (« cf. » ou « cfr » pour « confer », « frq. » pour « francique » parce que les autres abréviations potentielles pourraient être confondues avec des abréviations de « français », mot probable dans un contexte où « francique » peut être utilisé abrévié).

Answer (score 13):

Je vais juste citer [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographie), qui reporte l'usage que j'ai rencontré le plus couramment :

> - On abrège monsieur par *M.* et non *Mr* ni *Mr.*, qui sont l’abréviation de l’anglais *mister*.
> - On écrit en revanche *D<sup>r</sup>* et *M<sup>gr</sup>* (monseigneur) parce que dans leur cas ce *r* final se prononce.
> - L’abréviation de *messieurs* est *MM.*, *madame* s’abrège *M<sup>me</sup>* et *mademoiselle* en *M<sup>lle</sup>*, alors que *M<sup>e</sup>* renvoie à *maître*.

Comment: Remarque, on voit souvent *Mme* aussi. (Même si la convention typographique traditionnelle semble placer les dernières lettres d'un mot abrégé en position d'exposant.)

Comment: Pourquoi MM. pour messieurs?

Comment: Aucune idée, c'est plutôt étrange. S'il y a une vraie raison j'aimerais bien la connaître aussi.

Comment: j'ai une piste: *mes monsieurs* (MM donc) se serait contracté en *messieurs* (ça me semble fort plausible)

Comment: Il me semble que c'est simplement le pluriel. Je me souviens avoir vu JJOO pour Jeux Olympiques ou EEUU pour États Unis. La graphie n'est pas courante mais elle serait correcte.

Comment: 3.11.3. d'[abréviation](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/abreviations-01.html), d'Orthotypographie, confirme en l'occurence le *pluriel par doublement de lettres initiales*.

Answer (score 9):

Selon *Le lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* :

(édition 2002)

> Monsieur, madame, mademoiselle
>
>  Ces trois termes, qui sont des titres de civilité, suivent des règles d'emploi particulières :
>
> 1-  Ils s'abrègent au singulier comme au pluriel, devant le nom, le prénom ou le titre des personnes dont on parle ou qu'on désigne :
> MM. les conseillers sont en conférence avec M. le préfet.
> M<sup>me</sup> Durand, accompagnée de M<sup>lles</sup> Dupont et Dubois, fit une entrée remarquée.