# Quelle est la forme la plus correcte pour abréger le mot "salaire"?

Tags: vocabulaire, abréviations

J'ai essayé "slr." mais peut-être ça reste pas assez évident.
Y a-t-il une forme habituelle?

Le contexte serait principalement des conversations par SMS dans un degré de formalité où on utilise dejà souvent d'autres abréviations comme "soc." pour société, etc.

Comment: Il existe diverses abréviations selon le contexte. Une simple recherche « abréviation salaire » fournit de nombreuses possibilités.

Comment: D'accord, mais je ne trouve que de trop spécifiques pour le contexte, par example SMIC spécifiquement pour le salaire minimum,  ou bien "W" en termes macroéconomiques ("Wages") mais ce n'est pas le cas... D'ailleurs mon interlocuteur ne comprendrait pas une "W"

Comment: Il faudrait que tu précises le contexte dans lequel tu veux abréger ton mot, ici à qui tu parles et le sujet

Comment: Précisé. Merci.

Comment: Il y a peut-être la possibilité de trouver/employer un synonyme plus court, comme «ta/la **paye/paie**», par exemple.

Comment: Il n'y pas une forme "habituelle". Pas tout dans le vie est codifié. Vous pouvez l'inventer. Mettez vous d'accord avec votre interlocuteur. SAL, pourquoi pas?

Answer (score 1):

Salaire est rarement abrégé, surtout s'il apparaît seul. « **slr** » risque de ne pas être facilement compris sauf peut-être en langage « SMS » (comme slt = salut), ex :

> Slt, t'as 1 nouveau boulot! C koi ton slr?

Sinon, et surtout en association avec un autre mot, l'abréviation de salaire la plus courante est « **sal.** », par exemple:

> Sal. mensuel: xxxx €
>   Sal. annuel, sal. moyen, etc.

Comment: Merci, c'est mon opinion aussi que "slr." ne se laisse pas transmettre facilement. Si "sal." est la forme la plus courante ça résulterait plus naturel pour le récepteur du message.

Answer (score 1):

D'après les règles du langage SMS, il faudrait écrire:

> salR

Avec un "R" en majuscules pour dire qu'il s'agit du son "erre".

Cependant dans un contexte professionel on n'utilise pas le véritable langage SMS (qui est réservé à un usage informel), mais plutôt des abbréviations télégraphiques (comme "société" qui devient "soc."). Dans ce cas l'abbréviation usuelle est:

> sal.

Comment: +1 pour salR, je l'ai trouvé là, bien qu'au deuxième degré: [Ché nou **tu triple ton salR** et té en EDF açuré. RDV ce soir ds le bus du ST pour signé le contra.](http://www.forumst.net/topic/12501-transferts-saison-2009-2010/?page=40) Un vrai régal pour les yeux ;-)

Comment: "pour signé le contra" ? Vraiment? ;-) Je me demande si je dois rentrer en France ou pas - je ne vais plus m'y retrouver...

Comment: @Frank http://www.sciencesetavenir.fr/sante/le-langage-sms-est-il-un-danger-pour-l-orthographe_27185

Comment: @jlliagre - merci :-)

Answer (score 0):

Je ne pense pas qu'on abrège le mot "salaire" couramment. En fait, je ne pense pas avoir jamais vu d'abréviation pour ce mot, qui n'est de toute façon pas si long... Peut-être dans des sites d'offres d'emplois?

Answer (score 0):

C'est que la mécanique de formation de l'abréviation, dont on a [déjà parlé](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1135), est plus complexe que celle de la saisie prédictive ; à quand de vrais outils qui permettent de s'exprimer pleinement dans sa langue ?<sup>1</sup> Tout d'abord, on pourrait choisir la ou les premières lettres suivie(s) d'un point, mais le choix de la première lettre uniquement ne permet pas de comprendre le mot hors contexte ici. Alors on pourrait tronquer le mot en terminant avec une consonne qui serait suivie d'une voyelle qu'on omettrait avec le reste du mot, en terminant avec un point ; en suivant ce modèle, on pourrait ainsi obtenir « sal. » ou « salair. ». Le deuxième usage repose sur l'emploi de la première lettre accompagnée des dernières qu'on met au-dessus de la ligne, et qu'on peut facilement ramener à la ligne quand ce n'est pas prononçable ; il me semble que *sre* est prononçable si on considère que cie(C<sup>ie</sup>) et me(M<sup>e</sup>) le sont ; on obtiendrait ainsi s<sup>re</sup>. Dans le même ordre d'idée on peut rappeler que l'abréviation du mot société est selon plus d'une source du type S/s<sup>té</sup> / Sté, ([Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=soci%E9t%E9&i=&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/St%C3%A9) (de Bescherelle), [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1811)) et non « soc. » qui ne semble pas être conforme à l'usage antérieur (par ailleurs on a vérifié et on semble avoir l'abréviation S.S. pour *sa sainteté* i.e. un mot qui comme société débute par *s* et se termine par *té*.). Enfin avec des expressions latines on a l'initiale avec une lettre intérieure mais ça ne s'applique pas ici... Certaines [institutions](http://dictionnaire.carra.gouv.qc.ca/abreviations.asp#S) font aussi des choix particuliers avec la notion de salaire qu'on pourra trouver plus ou moins usuels, utiles.

---

> s. / sal. / salair. / s<sup>re</sup> 
>  (Tu gagnes) combien par
>   année ?
>  Combien/année ?
>   
> SAB (*Salaire annuel de base* en contexte des régimes de retraite du secteur public du [Québec](http://dictionnaire.carra.gouv.qc.ca/index.asp?id=630))

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> C'est non sans rappeler d'autres cas de contraintes techniques auxquelles on se plie trop souvent et qui finissent par produire des résultats douteux : par exemple le *a* majuscule avec l'accent grave, « À », un exploit de contorsion digitale avec une configuration traditionnelle du clavier français qui n'était pas entièrement adaptée à la richesse du fait français (!!!) nous a-t-on [déjà dit](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/67). Et maintenant les abréviations conformes à la saisie prédictive au portable dans un contexte où une contrainte artificielle et externe à la langue (la longueur du message et l'interface) est à l'origine d'un résultat qui n'est ni conforme à l'usage antérieur, ni l'équivalent d'une transcription phonétique cohérente. Ce qui n'empêche pas certains de s'en réjouir bêtement de ce français parcellaire en ajoutant heureusement dans leur [texte](http://www.sciencesetavenir.fr/sante/le-langage-sms-est-il-un-danger-pour-l-orthographe_27185), « *que les jeunes "texteurs" ne se réjouissent pas trop vite car, si selon cette étude, le niveau d'orthographe n'est pas impacté [sic] par les textos, il faut pour autant que les règles de l'orthographe conventionnel [sic] soit [sic] bien acquises pour pouvoir ensuite s'en affranchir.* ». On ne croyait si bien dire.</sub>