# Quelles sont les règles pour créer une abréviation ?

Tags: abréviations

Quelles sont les règles pour écrire un mot de façon abbrégée ?

Par exemple, je voudrais raccourcir le mot « coordonnées ». « Coord. » est-il une possibilité ?

Comment: Oui, réponse détaillée dans : [Quelle est l'abréviation correcte de « monsieur » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/quelle-est-labr%c3%a9viation-correcte-de-monsieur)

Comment: @jlliagre : Merci pour le comment. Faut-il attendre d'autres réponses ou accepter immédiatement le caractère doublé da ma question ?

Comment: Ta question est un peu plus large que celle dont j'ai fourni le lien. Tu n'es donc pas obligé de clore ta question. La réponse de N. Labrahmi propose des liens intéressants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J'ai bien aimé votre question, et après une recherche rapide, voici ce que j'ai pu trouver :

- > L’abréviation ne prend pas de point lorsque la dernière lettre est
  >   aussi la dernière lettre du mot abrégé. Par ailleurs, les abréviations
  >   ne s’accordent jamais (et encore moins les symboles)

  (Cf. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abr%C3%A9viation)
- Il existe un [dictionnaire d'abréviations](http://theleme.enc.sorbonne.fr/dico.php) qui reprend la liste de Maurice Prou dans *Manuel de paléographie latine et française*.
- > Une abréviation qui ne se compose que des premières lettres du mot est
  >   suivie d'un point. M. = Monsieur - réf. = référence. Une abréviation
  >   qui se termine par la dernière lettre du mot n'est pas suivie d'un
  >   point. Mme = Madame - bd = boulevard. Une abréviation composée de
  >   plusieurs lettres du mot n'est pas suivie d'un point. Mgr =
  >   Monseigneur - Mmes = Mesdames (Cf.
  >   http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01h.htm)

Je ne sais pas dans quelle mesure ces règles-là font autorité ou consensus, mais cela peut éventuellement permettre d'avoir de premiers éléments de réponse.

Comment: C'est super ! Je vous remercie vivement pour votre réponse ! Les liens sont également très utiles.

Comment: Je vous en prie, cela permet d'apprendre aussi de nouvelles choses :)